# How can i break the inheritance nature in java?

Tags: java

I have below parent class :-

```
class Parent {
    Parent() {
        System.out.print("Parent ");
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    Child() {
        System.out.print("Child");
    }
}
```

So when i execute `Child c = new Child();`

My output should be *"Child"* **Not** *"Parent Child"*

can we do that using reflection API?

Requirement :-
I have a long Junit Setup  hierarchy  Which I want to avoid for some of the classes

Comment: You can't. A constructor of a sub-class must always call a constructor of the super-class.

Comment: So delete the `println` from your `Parent` constructor.

Comment: No. I don't understand why you would want to do such a thing. You **cannot** create a class without calling a constructor; so if you need to create a `Parent` you need to call `Parent()`. As `Child` _is a_ `Parent`, `Parent()` must be called to create a `Child`. (while what I have said is not _strictly_ speaking true, the reasons why are well beyond your current level, and be ignored without loss of generality)

Comment: the real question is why you *think* you need that?

Comment: I have a long Junit Setup hierarchy Which I want to avoid for some of the classes

Comment: This is why we "prefer composition over inheritance".

Comment: @BoristheSpider can you specify in details

Answer (score -1):

What happens is when you create the Child class the Parent's class constructor is called first and then the Child's constructor.

What you could do if you must change what happens in the parent constructor is that you extract the related code into a protected method and this way you can override it in the Child class
**However it is error prone and not recommended** ([What's wrong with overridable method calls in constructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404301/whats-wrong-with-overridable-method-calls-in-constructors))

```
class Parent {
    Parent() {
       overridableInit();
    }
    protected void overridableInit() {
        System.out.print("Parent ");
    }
}

//If you want to extend the behavior:
class Child1 extends Parent {

    @Override
    protected void overridableInit() {
        super.overridableInit();
        System.out.print("Child1 ");
    }
}

//If you want to skip the Parent behavior:
class Child2 extends Parent {
    @Override
    protected void overridableInit() {
        System.out.print("Child2 ");
    }
}
```

Comment: "_You could extract the text into a field and override_" - one cannot override fields.

Comment: "You could extract the text into a field and override its value" - to be specific. But yes i didn't us the right words.

Comment: The usage of the word "override" is wrong when related to fields, reword your answer and perhaps provide an example. In any case, the OP cannot change the `Parent` so this answer is not relevant.